# today date only once toast message show

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, toast

I'm implementing  the concept of if today date is present one alert message show one time only.

Example 5-8-14 only once toast message show.

6-8-14 only once toast message show 
'
in every date only once toast show.

Edit:
Only after first start of App, a toast with current date should appear. If I start my app second or third time, then there should no toast appear

Comment: Vague question. Please be more clear and post some code.

Comment: Show your logic, and what did you try for this?

Comment: daily once Toast message show.Am open my app so many times but first time today date only once toast show.tommorrow am open app first time toast show

Answer (score 0):

**Logic:**

**What:**
 1. When ever you show the toast, Save the date/day in sharedPreferences.
 2. Then each time, compare the value of "today's date" with the sharedPref value, if its different, show the toast.

**How:**
 - Make a function for the toast, inside which update the Shared Pref value.
 - In an "if" loop, compare the default shared pref value - so when you run the app for the first time, it'l return the default value and enter the show toast function.

**Eg.**

```
if(!(sharedPrefSavedDate.equals(sharedPrefDefaultValue))){
if(!(String.valueOf(new SimpleDateFormat("dd").format(new java.util.Date())).equals(sharedPrefSavedDate)){
                             showToast();
}
}
```

Inside `showToast()`, save the value of today's date in Shared Preferences.

The saved value can be integer or String. Can change `.equals` to `!=` of `=` accordingly.

May require:
[How to use shared preferences](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3624280/how-to-use-sharedpreferences-in-android-to-store-fetch-and-edit-values)

[Example with integer on android developers](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Answer (score 0):

Look into sharedPreferences.
Here a Link to android developer: [sharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html)

Set a bool-value after first start and after each start check this value and if it's true, then don't show toast

GetDate:

```
Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("dd:MMMM:yyyy");
String strDate = sdf.format(c.getTime());
```

Link: [Get current time and date](http://www.asbhtechsolutions.com/android-tutorial/1-android-get-current-time-and-date)

Write:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPref.edit();
editor.putBool("Toast", True);
editor.putString("Date", strDate);
editor.commit();
```

Read:

```
SharedPreferences sharedPref = getActivity().getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
bool bToast = sharedPref.getBool("Toast", False);
String strDate = sharedPref.getString("Date", null);
```

Comment: and when will the bool-value be false? requirement is such that it would need to check date, not boolean value :)